# Gnome Software keyboard weirdness

Tags: gnome, keyboard, software-center, gtk, 16.04

In the new Gnome Software in 16.04, the keyboard is *weird* - whenever I type in the search bar, keys get pressed *twice*:

[image]

I've tried disabling "Key presses repeat when key is held down" in Control Center -> Keyboard.

Search bars and text fields in other GTK 3 apps work perfectly. This is on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem, did some searching and found this. It fixes the issue for me no longer getting double letters

Install ibus-gtk
In the terminal do

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3
```

Reboot. (Does not work until rebooted)

Should work now!

Comment: Sorry, but didn't work

Comment: Did you reboot? also try `sudo apt-get install ibus-gtk3`

Comment: Thank you! `ibus-gtk3` solved it. Please edit your answer to say `ibus-gtk3` instead of just `ibus-gtk`.

Comment: I have this issue only with a wired USB keyboard. Disabling keystrokes changes nothing on the wired and the command above + reboot didn't worked so far. Neither changing the input language

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 16.04.

I had previously disabled IBus when I was running <=15.10 due to an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33651898/737471) with the Jetbrains Pycharm IDE.

Renabling IBus fixed the issue with Gnome Software for me.

Try opening your system Settings ­> Language Support and ensuring the Keyboard input method at the bottom of the page is set to ibus. If it was set to none, reboot after you change the setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.10. with Gnome. 
I tried the `sudo apt-get install ibus gtk` fix before that and this did not work for me.

I had the language set on my first language (Dutch).

I changed it in the settings to English (United States) and this fixed it for me.