# USB keyboard on ubuntu 16.04.02 repeating Key strokes

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have the most bizarre thing happening.
I had a USB keyboard repeating keystrokes on a notebook with ubuntu 16.04.01 (but not the main one).

When I went to **keyboard options** to change stuff like key press repeat when held down. The USB keyboard would still repeat but the built in would not.

I tried to install **Laptop mode tools** to check if it was not some power configuration putting the USB keyboard on the blacklist but that did not work.

I upgraded to 16.04.02 and the problem was apparently solved.
Now the problem came and went (weirdly after I installed steam but I don't think this is necessarily related).

It's a cheap plastic usb keyboard with no bells and whistles and the machine was a fresh formatted one.

Any idea of a general direction for me to follow?

Comment: Possibly related? http://askubuntu.com/questions/760703/gnome-software-keyboard-weirdness

Comment: I think it's defintely related will try the solution and let you know